# The bills, the electricity

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article

I am confused by the grammar of my sentence. Can I use "it" to mean *electricity* or should I use *them* because I am talking about *lights*? Is the definite article optional before *electricity bills*, can I say just *electricity* without *the*?

1. I try to turn off the lights when I am not using *it*, because (the) electricity bills are expensive.
2. I try to turn off the lights when I am not using them, because the electricity bills are expensive.
3. I try to turn off the lights when I am not using them, because  electricity bills are expensive.
4. I try to turn off the lights when I am not using them, because (the) electricity is expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about *lights*, you really have to say *them*, because *lights* is plural.

*Electricity bills* without an article sounds like a general concept, like "electricity bills" in general.  *The* electric bills sounds like you're referring to some specific bills, probably the ones you get.  I would tend to use the article, because you do want to be specific: you don't mean that the bills everywhere, for everyone are high, you are referring to the ones that you can control.

(By the way, [Americans tend to say **electric** bill, not *electricity* bill](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=electric+bill%2Celectricity+bill&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3).)

Comment: can I use "the electricity" or just "electricity" in my sentence?

Comment: British people say 'electricity bill', and also I think we would tend to say that a bill was large or high; it was the electricity itself that was expensive.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey so it should be "the electricity bills are large or high in my sentence,but the electricity or electricity is expensive? With or without the article?

Comment: @AntoniaA - I suggest: _I try to turn off the lights when I am not using them, because electricity is expensive_.